# amchart5 two of the same chart on one page

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

FIXED, The issue was caused by the use of function when defining the IIFE. Since amCharts 5 makes use of ES6 classes, you cannot invoke a class constructor without new within a regular function block. To fix this issue, I needed to use an ES6 arrow function when defining the IIFE, like so: (() => { [code] })();

Original Question is Below.

I am attempting to display two identical gauges from AmCharts 5 on a single HTML page, but only one of them is appearing. In the JavaScript file, I have copied the code from one gauge to the other, using different div IDs.
Previously, in AmCharts 4, simply changing the div ID in the .js file was enough to achieve this, but in AmCharts 5, this does not appear to be the case. I have attempted to change the variables for the second gauge, such as using "root" for gauge one and "root2" for gauge two, and working through all variables, but to no avail.
I have also attempted to enclose them in separate functions with the code:

`(function () { Code……. })();`

Could you kindly advise me on how I can resolve this issue? I have attached the .js code below for both gauges.

```
// Create root element

var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv_gauge");

// Set themes

root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create chart

var chart = root.container.children.push(
  am5radar.RadarChart.new(root, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    startAngle: 180,
    endAngle: 360
  })
);

chart.getNumberFormatter().set("numberFormat", "#'%'");

// Create axis and its renderer
var axisRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererCircular.new(root, {
  innerRadius: -40
});

axisRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
  stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
  visible: true,
  strokeOpacity: 0.8
});

var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    maxDeviation: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    strictMinMax: true,
    renderer: axisRenderer
  })
);

// Add clock hand
var axisDataItem = xAxis.makeDataItem({});

var clockHand = am5radar.ClockHand.new(root, {
  pinRadius: 50,
  radius: am5.percent(100),
  innerRadius: 50,
  bottomWidth: 0,
  topWidth: 0
});

clockHand.pin.setAll({
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
  strokeWidth: 1,
  strokeDasharray: [2, 2]
});
clockHand.hand.setAll({
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
  strokeWidth: 0.5
});

var bullet = axisDataItem.set(
  "bullet",
  am5xy.AxisBullet.new(root, {
    sprite: clockHand
  })
);

xAxis.createAxisRange(axisDataItem);

var label = chart.radarContainer.children.push(
  am5.Label.new(root, {
    centerX: am5.percent(50),
    textAlign: "center",
    centerY: am5.percent(50),
    fontSize: "1.5em"
  })
);

axisDataItem.set("value", 50);
bullet.get("sprite").on("rotation", function () {
  var value = axisDataItem.get("value");
  label.set("text", Math.round(value).toString() + "%");
});

setInterval(function () {
  var value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

  axisDataItem.animate({
    key: "value",
    to: value,
    duration: 500,
    easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
  });

  axisRange0.animate({
    key: "endValue",
    to: value,
    duration: 500,
    easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
  });

  axisRange1.animate({
    key: "value",
    to: value,
    duration: 500,
    easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
  });
}, 2000);

chart.bulletsContainer.set("mask", undefined);

var colorSet = am5.ColorSet.new(root, {});

var axisRange0 = xAxis.createAxisRange(
  xAxis.makeDataItem({
    above: true,
    value: 0,
    endValue: 50
  })
);

axisRange0.get("axisFill").setAll({
  visible: true,
  fill: colorSet.getIndex(0)
});

axisRange0.get("label").setAll({
  forceHidden: true
});

var axisRange1 = xAxis.createAxisRange(
  xAxis.makeDataItem({
    above: true,
    value: 50,
    endValue: 100
  })
);

axisRange1.get("axisFill").setAll({
  visible: true,
  fill: colorSet.getIndex(4)
});

axisRange1.get("label").setAll({
  forceHidden: true
});

// Make stuff animate on load
chart.appear(1000, 100);



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ... First gauge code (same as before with div ID changed)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Gauge 2 Facility-1
var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv_gauge_2");

// Set themes
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

// Create chart
var chart = root.container.children.push(
  am5radar.RadarChart.new(root, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    startAngle: 180,
    endAngle: 360
  })
);

chart.getNumberFormatter().set("numberFormat", "#'%'");

// Create axis and its renderer
var axisRenderer = am5radar.AxisRendererCircular.new(root, {
  innerRadius: -40
});

axisRenderer.grid.template.setAll({
  stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
  visible: true,
  strokeOpacity: 0.8
});

var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    maxDeviation: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    strictMinMax: true,
    renderer: axisRenderer
  })
);

// Add clock hand
var axisDataItem = xAxis.makeDataItem({});

var clockHand = am5radar.ClockHand.new(root, {
  pinRadius: 50,
  radius: am5.percent(100),
  innerRadius: 50,
  bottomWidth: 0,
  topWidth: 0
});

clockHand.pin.setAll({
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
  strokeWidth: 1,
  strokeDasharray: [2, 2]
});
clockHand.hand.setAll({
  fillOpacity: 0,
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  stroke: am5.color(0x000000),
  strokeWidth: 0.5
});

var bullet = axisDataItem.set(
  "bullet",
  am5xy.AxisBullet.new(root, {
    sprite: clockHand
  })
);

xAxis.createAxisRange(axisDataItem);

var label = chart.radarContainer.children.push(
  am5.Label.new(root, {
    centerX: am5.percent(50),
    textAlign: "center",
    centerY: am5.percent(50),
    fontSize: "1.5em"
  })
);

axisDataItem.set("value", 50);
bullet.get("sprite").on("rotation", function () {
  var value = axisDataItem.get("value");
  label.set("text", Math.round(value).toString() + "%");
});

setInterval(function () {
  var value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

  axisDataItem.animate({
    key: "value",
    to: value,
    duration: 500,
    easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
  });

  axisRange0.animate({
    key: "endValue",
    to: value,
    duration: 500,
    easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
  });

  axisRange1.animate({
    key: "value",
    to: value,
    duration: 500,
    easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
  });
}, 2000);

chart.bulletsContainer.set("mask", undefined);

var colorSet = am5.ColorSet.new(root, {});

var axisRange0 = xAxis.createAxisRange(
  xAxis.makeDataItem({
    above: true,
    value: 0,
    endValue: 50
  })
);

axisRange0.get("axisFill").setAll({
  visible: true,
  fill: colorSet.getIndex(0)
});

axisRange0.get("label").setAll({
  forceHidden: true
});

var axisRange1 = xAxis.createAxisRange(
  xAxis.makeDataItem({
    above: true,
    value: 50,
    endValue: 100
  })
);

axisRange1.get("axisFill").setAll({
  visible: true,
  fill: colorSet.getIndex(4)
});

axisRange1.get("label").setAll({
  forceHidden: true
});

// Make stuff animate on load
chart.appear(1000, 100);

// End gauge 2
```

I have tried the following:

I placed `(function () { Code……. }) CODE ();` around each gauge.
I have tried placing the gauges into two seperate .js files
I have tried changing all variables in the second gauge.
I have tried similar approaches as used on chart.js, but as this is amcharts it doesn't work.

On all of the above, only the first gauge appears. I am out of ideas on how to get both to show on the same page.

Comment: You redefine `root` to refer to the second gauge. I suggest using different variable names for everything to do with the second gauge (i.e., define `root2`, `chart2`, etc.).

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey I tried that, as placed in post. Unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: FIxed, The issue was caused by the use of function when defining the IIFE. Since amCharts 5 makes use of ES6 classes, you cannot invoke a class constructor without new within a regular function block. To fix this issue, I needed to  use an ES6 arrow function when defining the IIFE, like so: `(() => { [code] })(); `

Comment: If you have figured the answer yourself, you should post that as an answer -- and leave the question as it was.